# Android accessibility: talkback header navigation using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, header, accessibility, talkback

I'm trying to implement "navigate through headers" in Talbalk, using one `RecyclerView`.

What I want is that, providing that the user has "Headings" as the navigation mode in Talkback, when they swipe up/down, the should jump directly to the next header.

For this, I am marking some views as "header" using:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityHeading(view, true)
```

The problem I am experiencing is that in my `RecyclerView`, the behaviour is erratic.
It fails to find the next/list header, depending whether they are visible or not in the screen.
I wonder if it’s due to being implemented with a `RecyclerView`, and some views not really in the hierarchy due to the recycling mechanism: whether a view is a header or not is not is flagged in the view itself.
If the next header is not yet view hierarchy, how could this work? It should be impossible.

But then, does this mean this API is incompatible with `RecyclerView`?  “Navigation though headers” screams RecyclerView, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a bit frustrating, but because the [`ReceyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview) is aimed at optimizing the number of `view`s that are loaded, it wouldn't be possible for it to know where to scroll to because that header `view` may or may not have been loaded at that time.

> When an item scrolls off the screen, RecyclerView doesn't destroy its view. Instead, RecyclerView reuses the view for new items that have scrolled onscreen. RecyclerView improves performance and your app's responsiveness, and it reduces power consumption.

What you could do is use the [`action`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#accessible-actions) API to make custom actions. You could create a custom action for each heading in the list for easier navigation. Then just associate those actions with the `RecyclerView.` Something like this:

```
    val recyclerViewLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = recyclerViewLayoutManager
    recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(...)
    (adapter as MyAdapter)
        .headingPositions() // create a function in your adapter to read the positions of your headings, and a label for the heading name. This could be a Map<String, Int>
        .map { headingWithPosition ->
        ViewCompat.addAccessibilityAction(
            this, headingWithPosition.key
        ) { _, _ ->
            // scrollToPosition(headingWithPosition.value)
            recyclerViewLayoutManager
                .scrollToPositionWithOffset(headingWithPosition.value, 0)
            true
        }
    }
```

These actions are announced when attached to a `view` as "actions available." To use them, use the TalkBack gesture action to open the menu (typically `swipe up and right`, select `actions`)

[image: Large list of names displayed in an app. User opens the TalkBack menu with a swipe up and right. Chooses actions. Selects "E". The "E" heading is displayed at the top of the list. The user does the same with A and J]

I did try this and I can't say I'm a huge fan, the `scrollToPosition` puts the element last in the list and the focus remains at the top, but it does work. If you use the [`LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,int)), you can choose the pixel offset from the top, which is nicer.

In all fairness I think a filtering option would be more universal in it's utility.

Comment: What I ended up doing is: 1. the headers are not focusable for accessibility. They are visually rendered, but skipped for talkback navigation. 2. The content description for each item has the header as part of the read screen. This way, each item is more in context to the section it belongs to when being read.

Comment: Hey there - I just hope your users benefit and you're not making more work for yourself. By putting something intended for structural purposes like the headings as part of the content description, the concern is that folks using TalkBack won't be able to navigate by the headings granularity (3 finger swipe right to locate, swipe up and down to use). If that isn't present, the purpose of headings is lost.

Comment: With that said, I'm glad you have a solution and thanks for asking this question - I really enjoyed coming up with my answer, even if it's not what you want for your app :)